# Grid of 10 cells (2 rows, 5 columns) within a single UITableView in the Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a UITableView in my Storyboard.

I want a single cell which contains a grid of 10 cells (2 rows, 5 columns) with labels that are evenly distributed and scales well on different devices.

I currently have:

```
(UITableViewCell)
    Content View
    |   Stack View (Vertical)
    |   |   Stack View (Horizontal)
    |   |   |    Label 0
    |   |   |    Label 1
    |   |   |    Label 2
    |   |   |    Label 3
    |   |   |    Label 4
    |   |   Stack View (Horizontal)
    |   |   |    Label 5
    |   |   |    Label 6
    |   |   |    Label 7
    |   |   |    Label 8
    |   |   |    Label 9
```

I've set-up contraints on the outer Stack View (Vertical) such that it has `0` distance from the 4 edges.

Unfortunately this renders like this in the Storyboard:

[image]

(only 4 labels appear in the 2nd row because I forgot to add a label)

...which isn't evenly-spaced.

What steps do I need to take to make it render how I want? Am I even doing it correctly? Should I use a nested `CollectionView` instead?

### Update

Thank you all for the `Distribution: Fill Equally` setting. It now renders correctly in the Storyboard.

[image]

However on my iPod Touch it looks like this:

[image]

What's up?

Comment: do you just want the horizontal stackview to space the labels out evenly?

Comment: It will be safer and easier to use Collection View.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the [distribution property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStackViewDistribution) of your horizontal stackviews to `.FillEqually`

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my question with a new problem.

Comment: if you change the background colour of your tableview, does it look like the table view is squashed as well or just the stackview?

Comment: The UITableView is fine, the StackView is squashed - even when I set a zero constraint.

Comment: hmm i cant tell what could be going wrong, but my best guess is it is because of autolayouts, maybe try some different distribution properties and see if they act any different